# Video Processing Options Not Available

Tags: video

I seem to be having video issues. When I import videos they only show up as audio. I tried the Codec Support section of [Documentation Center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExportingVideo.html) with no luck:

When I run the

```
SystemOptions["VideoProcessingOptions"]
```

I get this error message:

> SystemOptions::sysname: VideoProcessingOptions is not a known
> SystemOption.

The following doesn't work either:

```
Keys[$VideoEncoders]
```

> Keys::invrl: The argument $VideoEncoders is not a valid Association or a list of rules.

**FFMPEG** is installed and working on Windows. When I run the version test `ffmpeg -version` in cmd I get:

> ffmpeg version N-101658-g75fd3e1519 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg
> developers built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320 configuration:
> --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp libavutil      56. 71.100 / 56. 71.100 libavcodec     58.135.100 / 58.135.100 libavformat    58.
> 77.100 / 58. 77.100 libavdevice    58. 14.100 / 58. 14.100 libavfilter     7.111.100 /  7.111.100 libswscale      5. 10.100 /  5. 10.100 libswresample   3. 10.100 /  3. 10.100 libpostproc    55. 10.100 / 55.
> 10.100

Comment: From your version number, it seems that you have a development version installed instead of a release one, which should return something like `ffmpeg version 4.3.2` instead. Is it possible that this is the cause of the miscommunication between the two systems?

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, I will try reinstalling with another version.